# Hide Categories from WordPress Dashboard by ID and Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently went searching for a solution to hide specific categories by ID on a WordPress dashboard for individual custom post types. I stumbled upon the following code and was able to get half way there by hiding categories for logged in user.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion' );

function wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion() {
    if( current_user_can('administrator')  )
        add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions($exclusions,$args) {
    return $exclusions . " AND ( t.term_id <> 43 )  AND ( t.term_id <> 42 )";
}
```

Now I want to alter this code to hide ID specified categories taking the custom post type into account. I know, I can pass an argument with the current_user_can but I'm not sure how to phrase it. Unfortunately a custom taxonomy which I have implemented in other aspects of the site is not going to work in this instance.

I thought all I had to do was swap the if statement conditional with a get_post_type but it did not work. Any ideas?

```
'andytoday' == get_post_type()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to filter by post type. The filter `list_terms_exclusions` acts on `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php` (nothing to do with post type), but **doesn't work** on `/wp-admin/edit.php` (where post type matters). . . . Shouldn't you filter by *custom taxonomy*?

Comment: I was having same question as you have in my mind. But, my clients wants this to be filter by post type. He said I want this only.

Comment: Can you please, let me know how I can filter it by custom taxonomy?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to clarify this issue.